# Image not showing in a JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

Here are my two code samples:

```
public class Display extends JPanel
{
    protected BufferedImage buffer;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Display()
    {
        super();
        //setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        buffer = new BufferedImage(PONG_WIDTH, PONG_WIDTH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics2D g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Server extends Display
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Server() throws IOException
    {
        super();

        Graphics2D g = buffer.createGraphics();
        g.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, (PONG_HEIGHT-RACKET_HEIGHT)/2, RACKET_WIDTH, RACKET_HEIGHT);
        repaint();
```

EDIT: Add the `main`method:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("Test2");
        f.setSize(1000, 1000);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        try{
            Server s = new Server();
            f.add(s); //or f.setContentPane(s);
            s.repaint();
            f.setVisible(true);

            s.play();
        }
        catch (IOException e){}
    }
}
```

Why does the panel shows up blank or black if I uncomment the second line of `Display`'s constructor, when I draw several shapes in the subclass? I've been trying to find out the answer but every one of my attempts fell short.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen if you uncomment it?

Comment: Do you know what `extends JFrame` means?! So why are you creating a new JFrame in your main?

Comment: @blahfunk: Uh... What I meant is that the shapes I draw do not show no matter if I set the BG color or not. Tobi: Uh, you're right, but that's not the problem and you know that.

Comment: "But that's not the problem and you know that..." Not needed.

Comment: Neither is your comment.

Comment: Sorry, clean code is always needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such method `protected void paintComponent(Graphics2D g)` in the component hierarchy, it should actually be `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` <- Note the formal parameter requirements of the method

You should be calling `Graphics#dispose` on the `Graphics` context you created from the `BufferedImage` once you're done with it, this could prevent some platforms from rendering the image properly (as well as prevent the program from consuming system resources).

You should be creating and modifying the state of the UI only from within the context of the EDT, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.

There's also need reason to extend directly from `JFrame`, apart from introducing confusion into you code, you're not actually adding any features to the class.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems that was the problem.